# Condition for Baumslag-Solitar group to be virtually abelian

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, infinite-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

The Baumslag-Solitar group is the group given by the presentation
$$
BS(p, q) = \langle a, b \mid a^{-1}b^p a = b^q \rangle
$$
where $p,q \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$.

I have read that this group is virtually abelian (i.e. contains a finite index abelian subgroup) if and only if $|p| = |q|$, but this is given without citation. I have also been unable to find this (or an equivalent statement) in any other papers. However I have found the result that $BS(p,q)$ is residually finite if and only if $|p| = |q|$ or at least one of $|p|$ and $|q|$ is $1$.

I have been trying to extend this condition to show that in the first case $BS(p, q)$ is virtually abelian (and the converse), but have so far been unsuccessful.

I've also been trying that if $|p| \neq |q|$ but at least one is $1$, then $BS(p,q)$ is not virtually abelian. It is clear that in this case you get a semidirect product of two copies of $\mathbb{Z}$, but I've been unable to show no finite index abelian subgroups exist.

Thanks for any hints/help!

Comment: I don't believe that. When $|p|,|q| > 1$ the subgroup $\langle a,bab^{-1} \rangle$ is free, which is certainly not virtually abelian. When $|p|=1$ and $|q|>1$, the group is metacyclic and not virtually abelian. It is virtually abelian only when $|p|=|q|=1$.

Comment: @DerekHolt It was actually in your paper "Groups With Context-Free Co-word Problem" ([link for others](http://wrap.warwick.ac.uk/746/1/WRAP_Holt_Context_free_co-word.pdf)) that I read the statement. In the proof of Theorem 13 it states: "It (Baumslag-Solitar Group) is well known that G is virtually abelian precisely when $p = \pm q$".

Comment: I messed up the formatting of the quote, which should be: "It is well known that G (The Baumslag-Solitar Group) is virtually abelian precisely when $p = \pm q$".

Comment: That's unfortunate, I conveniently have no memory of which of the four authors was responsible for that aberration. For the record, the Baumslag-Solitar groups do have context-sensitive coword problem when $p \ne \pm q$, because they are virutally a direct product of a abelian (in fact cyclic) group and a free group in that case.

Comment: @DerekHolt No problem about not remembering, it is quite an old paper at this point. So just to clarify you're saying that the correct statement should be that a Baumslag-Solitar  group has context-free coword problem if and only if $p = \pm q$.

Comment: Yes that's right. I think that was what we intended as the statement, but somehow it got corrupted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll expand my comment into an answer. We can assume that $1 \le p\le |q|$.

If $p \ge 2$, then the free reduction of a word in the generators $a$ and $c := bab^{-1}$ does not involve any power $b^k$ of $b$ with $|k| \ge 2$, so by Britton's lemma on  HNN-extensions, the subgroup $\langle a,c \rangle$ is freely generated by $a$ and $c$, and is not virtually abelian.

When $p=1$ and $|q| \ge 2$, the normal closure of $\langle b \rangle$ in $G$ is abelian but not finitely generated. Since any subgroup of a finitely generated virtually abelian group is itself finitely generated, $G$ cannot be virtually abelian in this case.

When $p=|q|=1$ it is easy to see that $G$ is either free abelian of rank $2$ or it has a subgroup of index $2$ (i.e.$\langle a^2,b \rangle$) that is free abelian, so $G$ is virtually abelian in the case.

When $|p|=|q|$ we can describe the structure of the group very precisely, but it is still not virtually abelian when $|p|>1$. For example, if $p=q>1$, then the normal closure of $\langle a \rangle$ in $G$ is a free group of rank $q-1$, with a free basis cycled by conjugation by $b$.

Answer (score 2):

If $|m|\neq |n|$ then it has the solvable quotient $\mathbf{Z}\ltimes_{m/n}\mathbf{Z}[1/mn]$, which is not virtually abelian.

If $|m|=|n|\ge 2$, then killing $b^n$ yields the free product $\mathbf{Z}\ast(\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z})$, which is not virtually abelian.

In both cases, $\mathrm{BS}(m,n)$ having such a quotient is therefore not virtually abelian (actually not virtually nilpotent and even has exponential growth: it has a free semigroup on 2 generators).

In the remaining case, $|m|=|n|=1$, and then $\mathrm{BS}(m,n)$ is virtually abelian (abelian if $mn=1$, has an abelian subgroup of index 2 if $mn=-1$).